# vuejs router and similar routes

Tags: vue.js, router, vue-router

How do I make router understand /{id}/{dateid} and something like /admin/events as two different routes? Right now it tries to load page corresponding to the first route when I try to navigate through some other routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) the order of the declaration matters.

> the earlier a route is defined, the higher priority it gets

So making `/admin/events` to be before `/{id}/{dateid}` would solve the issue.